# Views: Link Title using Text URL field (GUID)

Tags: 7, views, feeds

I've created a feed within aggretator that I am displaying using views. I have a title field and a separate GUID field, which contains the link to each specific item's audio podcast. However, **when I opt to display the Title as a link, it simply links to the RSS feed's URL**. I would like to make it link to the GUID field, which contains that title's audio URL.

*How can I use one field in Views to serve as the link of another field?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you know the link and can construct it from the GUID field (either by some/text/[guid_field_machine_name]/maybe/more/text or just [guid_field_machine_name] or what have you):

1. Using the dropdown arrow to the right of the Fields section of your view, select "Rearrange"
2. Move the GUID field above your title field and save
3. Make sure your title field no longer has the link box checked off, because we're going to use a different link box.
4. Click on the title field to pull up the settings where you unchecked the link box. This time, select the Rewrite options.
5. Select the link option under the rewrite options. This will show you a text box where you can use fields that appear above the title field in your rearranged list of fields in a link to add to the title field. In this box you should put your GUID url, using [guid_field_machine_name] for the GUID field.

If you have questions, let me know, I can definitely provide more specific directions with a bit more information from you, like what exactly the GUID field contains and stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think I may have varied slightly, but this got me there! Now I get the whole re-write thing, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Include both field. And in rewrite field use something like this

```
<a href="[guid-link]">[title]</a>
```

You can use replacement tokens to search for proper token.
Also re-arrange the fields to list guid before title in order to show up in replacement token. also check exclude from display in guid field settings.