# How to create a link for field value?

Tags: views, entities, navigation

I am using views in that views i can able to give only title field as a link.I want to give field value also as link.while clicking on field link i need history of that field

> > example-In my content i have one field like warnings(newbirth,live,dead).when saving the content it is saving in view after that again the same field i am updating so thats why i think to do that field as link while clicking on that link suppose it is DEAD then it should show previous data like NEWBIRTH,LIVE

any suggestions...Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have the field and the link included in your views

The steps are as follow:

- Using the dropdown arrow to the right of the Fields section of your
  view, select "Rearrange"
- Move the history link field above your field that you want to link  and save
- Make sure your history link field no longer has the link box checked
  off, because we're going to use a different link box.
- Click on the  field to pull up the settings, select the Rewrite
  options. Select the link option under the rewrite options. This will
  show you a text box where you can use fields that appear above the
  title field in your rearranged list of fields in a link to add to the
  title field. In this box you should put your history link, using
  [history_link_machine_name] for the  field.

Similar answer can be found here [Views: Link Title using Text URL field (GUID)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178925/views-link-title-using-text-url-field-guid/178927#178927)

Comment: @ Shabir - thanks for your response i will check with this and come back to you.

Comment: @ Shabir - There is no history link in my fields in view ..how can i give the history link in field?

Comment: what do you mean by history of that link?

Comment: If you mean revisions then Use the track_field_changes module, it enables you side by side history of your field in views

Comment: @ Shabbir - i mean history = revisions.i have added revision field above of my warning field. from your last point last line means  want to give  my field  warnings machine name or revisions machine name?

Comment: revision machine name

Comment: @ Shabir - there are different type of revision fields is there when adding revision field in view which one i can add? to get only history of my warning field.

Comment: @ Shabir - i have updated my scn shot above..

Comment: @ All - is there anybody ..any other suggestion  regarding this que?